# How to check type of variable in Java?

Tags: java

How can I check to make sure my variable is an int, array, double, etc...?

Edit: For example, how can I check that a variable is an array? Is there some function to do this?

Comment: Take a look to the [Reflection API](http://download.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/reflect/).

Comment: Very related question with answers here: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2674554/how-do-you-know-a-variable-type-in-java.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How do you know a variable type in java?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2674554/how-do-you-know-a-variable-type-in-java)

Answer (score 142):

Java is a statically typed language, so the compiler does most of this checking for you.  Once you declare a variable to be a certain type, the compiler will ensure that it is only ever assigned values of that type (or values that are sub-types of that type).

The examples you gave (`int`, array, `double`) these are all primitives, and there are no sub-types of them.  Thus, if you declare a variable to be an `int`:

```
int x;
```

You can be sure it will only ever hold `int` values.

If you declared a variable to be a `List`, however, it is possible that the variable will hold sub-types of `List`.  Examples of these include `ArrayList`, `LinkedList`, etc.

If you did have a `List` variable, and you needed to know if it was an `ArrayList`, you could do the following:

```
List y;
...
if (y instanceof ArrayList) { 
  ...its and ArrayList...
}
```

However, if you find yourself thinking you need to do that, you may want to rethink your approach.  In most cases, if you follow object-oriented principles, you will not need to do this.  There are, of course, exceptions to every rule, though.

Comment: The instanceof operator only determines the datatype of the object referred to by the variable. It does not determine the datatype of the actual VARIABLE as originally requested.

Comment: This does not answer the question effectively. Glen Pierce's, `a.getClass().getName()` IMO, should be the accepted answer.

Answer (score 53):

Actually quite easy to roll your own tester, by abusing Java's method overload ability. Though I'm still curious if there is an official method in the sdk.

Example:

```
class Typetester {
    void printType(byte x) {
        System.out.println(x + " is an byte");
    }
    void printType(int x) {
        System.out.println(x + " is an int");
    }
    void printType(float x) {
        System.out.println(x + " is an float");
    }
    void printType(double x) {
        System.out.println(x + " is an double");
    }
    void printType(char x) {
        System.out.println(x + " is an char");
    }
}
```

then:

```
Typetester t = new Typetester();
t.printType( yourVariable );
```

Comment: Not a good method IMO. What happens if I pass some arbitrary type that is not defined in your Typetester class - in this instance String, for example?

Comment: @TashPemhiwa then add String and Object to the choices. Creativity and problem solving are a programmers best assets.

Comment: Still this can only deal with a fixed set of pre-defined classes (which defeats the purpose of object orientation/polymorphism) and will only give you something like "unknown class" for objects of any other class

Comment: The choice of which signature happens at compile time, not runtime.  So this technique won't tell you anything you don't already know at compile time. 
 https://docs.oracle.com/javase/specs/jls/se7/html/jls-15.html#jls-15.12.2

Comment: @Algoman getting something like “unknown class” wouldn’t be the worst thing. The worst thing is to get wrong answers, e.g. when trying `short x = 42; printType(x);` In fact, if someone adds a “helpful” `void printType(Object x)` overload there won’t be any “unknown class” results at all, but only potentially wrong results…

Answer (score 44):

`a.getClass().getName()` - will give you the datatype of the actual object referred to by `a`, but not the datatype that the variable `a` was originally declared as or subsequently cast to.

`boolean b = a instanceof String` - will give you whether or not the actual object referred to by `a` is an instance of a specific class.
Again, the datatype that the variable `a` was originally declared as or subsequently cast to has no bearing on the result of the instanceof operator.

I took this information from:
[How do you know a variable type in java?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2674554/how-know-a-variable-type-in-java)

This can happen. I'm trying to parse a `String` into an int and I'd like to know if my `Integer.parseInt(s.substring(a, b))` is kicking out an int or garbage before I try to sum it up.

By the way, this is known as Reflection. Here's some more information on the subject: http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/reflect/

Answer (score 34):

Just use:

```
.getClass().getSimpleName();
```

Example:

```
StringBuilder randSB = new StringBuilder("just a String");
System.out.println(randSB.getClass().getSimpleName());
```

Output:

```
StringBuilder
```

Comment: I suggest noting that this does not work if `randSB` holds NULL.

Answer (score 16):

You may work with Integer instead of int, Double instead of double, etc. (such classes exists for all primitive types).
Then you may use the operator instanceof, like `if(var instanceof Integer){...}`

Comment: All we need is a valid use-case.

Comment: Sounds like the most efficient approach .

Answer (score 9):

Well, I think checking the type of variable can be done this way.

```
public <T extends Object> void checkType(T object) {    
    if (object instanceof Integer)
        System.out.println("Integer ");
    else if(object instanceof Double)
        System.out.println("Double ");
    else if(object instanceof Float)
        System.out.println("Float : ");
    else if(object instanceof List)
        System.out.println("List! ");
    else if(object instanceof Set)
        System.out.println("Set! ");
}
```

This way you need not have multiple overloaded methods. I think it is good practice to use collections over arrays due to the added benefits. Having said that, I do not know how to check for an array type. Maybe someone can improve this solution. Hope this helps!

P.S Yes, I know that this doesn't check for primitives as well.

Answer (score 6):

The first part of your question is meaningless. There is no circumstance in which you don't know the type of a primitive variable at compile time.

Re the second part, the only circumstance that you don't already know whether a variable is an array is if it is an Object. In which case `object.getClass().isArray()` will tell you.

Comment: I could have a hashmap from string to object, put an int in that hashmap, and pull it back out. Only thing I know is that it's an "object" and could have to check for what type it is. Not saying it's good, just saying it's possible.

Comment: @matty-d the scenario you describe, is about the *type of the object*, not the type of a variable. In that regard, I would even say that the scenario of a variable of type `Object` referring to an array instance, is meaningless, as the *type of the variable* still is `Object`. Ironically, things have changed in the meanwhile, as nowadays you can declare variables with `var` and indeed not know what type the variable has. But, of course, the right way to deal with this, is not to use `var` when the type is unclear, not to try to find out the type after the fact.

Answer (score 6):

I did it using: `if(x.getClass() == MyClass.class){...}`

Answer (score 4):

I wasn't happy with any of these answers, and the one that's right has no explanation and negative votes so I searched around, found some stuff and edited it so that it is easy to understand. Have a play with it, not as straight forward as one would hope.

```
//move your variable into an Object type
Object obj=whatYouAreChecking;
System.out.println(obj);

// moving the class type into a Class variable
Class cls=obj.getClass();
System.out.println(cls);

// convert that Class Variable to a neat String
String answer = cls.getSimpleName();
System.out.println(answer);
```

Here is a method:

```
public static void checkClass (Object obj) {
    Class cls = obj.getClass();
    System.out.println("The type of the object is: " + cls.getSimpleName());       
}
```

Comment: works with primitive types as well but it lists "Integer" for a regular integer.

Comment: This prints the type of the object but not the type of the variable. This is best illustrated by the fact that the variable `obj` has type `Object` and when the caller doesn’t have a variable at all, e.g. `checkClass("foo")`, that variable of type `Object` is the only variable around and still, the method will print “`String`”.

Answer (score 4):

Basically , For example :

```
public class Kerem
{
    public static void main(String[] args)
    {
        short x = 10;
        short y = 3;
        Object o = y;
        System.out.println(o.getClass()); // java.lang.Short
    }

}
```

Answer (score 2):

I hit this question as I was trying to get something similar working using Generics. Taking some of the answers and adding getClass().isArray() I get the following that seems to work.

```
public class TypeTester <T extends Number>{

<T extends Object> String tester(T ToTest){

    if (ToTest instanceof Integer) return ("Integer");
    else if(ToTest instanceof Double) return ("Double");
    else if(ToTest instanceof Float) return ("Float");
    else if(ToTest instanceof String) return ("String");
    else if(ToTest.getClass().isArray()) return ("Array");
    else return ("Unsure");
}
}
```

I call it with this where the myArray part was simply to get an Array into callFunction.tester() to test it.

```
public class Generics {
public static void main(String[] args) {
    int [] myArray = new int [10];

    TypeTester<Integer> callFunction = new TypeTester<Integer>();
    System.out.println(callFunction.tester(myArray));
}
}
```

You can swap out the myArray in the final line for say 10.2F to test Float etc

Answer (score 1):

None of these answers work if the variable is an uninitialized generic type

And from what I can find, it's only possible using an [extremely ugly workaround](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/182636/how-to-determine-the-class-of-a-generic-type?noredirect=1&lq=1), or by passing in an initialized parameter to your function, making it in-place, see here:

```
<T> T MyMethod(...){ if(T.class == MyClass.class){...}}
```

Is NOT valid because you cannot pull the type out of the `T` parameter directly, since it is erased at runtime time.

```
<T> void MyMethod(T out, ...){ if(out.getClass() == MyClass.class){...}}
```

This works because the caller is responsible to instantiating the variable `out` before calling. This will still throw an exception if out is null when called, but compared to the linked solution, this is by far the easiest way to do this

I know this is a kind of specific application, but since this is the first result on google for finding the type of a variable with java (and given that `T` is a kind of variable), I feel it should be included

Answer (score 1):

```
var.getClass().getSimpleName()
```

Let's take a example

```
String[] anArrayOfStrings = { "Agra", "Mysore", "Chandigarh", "Bhopal" };
List<String> strList = Arrays.asList(anArrayOfStrings); 

anArrayOfStrings.getClass().getSimpleName() //res =>  String[]
strList.getClass().getSimpleName() // res => ArrayList
```

Answer (score 0):

You can check it easily using `Java.lang.Class.getSimpleName()` Method Only if variable has non-primitive type. It doesnt work with primitive types int ,long etc.

reference - [Here is the Oracle docs link](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/Class.html)

Comment: Thanks for the hint. I was focusing on the type/array checking example, though, not what to do within the logic.

Comment: Correction: I thought you'd answered to my example, where `getSimpleName()` actually works as intended. I'd second checking types against Strings. For this, I'd recommend `instanceof` and `getClass().isAssignableFrom()`, as shown above. If you have primitives, then there's no need for checking - if you've got boxed Objects, use `i instanceof Integer` and similar instead, or, for only numbers `n instanceof Number`.

Answer (score 0):

```
public static void chkType(Object var){     
        String type = var.getClass().toString();
        System.out.println(type.substring(16));     
        //assertEquals(type,"class java.lang.Boolean");
        //assertEquals(type,"class java.lang.Character");
        //assertEquals(type,"class java.lang.Integer");
        //assertEquals(type,"class java.lang.Double");      
    }
```

Comment: This prints the data type but does not answer the question. Where is the check for array?

Answer (score 0):

A simple solution I found was the following rather than wondering about fire command. Also, you can check this [article](https://www.delftstack.com/howto/java/how-to-check-type-of-a-variable-in-java/)

```java
public class DataTypeCheck 
{

    public static void main(String[] args)
    {
        String jobTitle = "Agent";
        int employeeId = 7;
        double floating= 10.0;
        String bond = jobTitle + employeeId;

        System.out.println(((Object)floating).getClass().getSimpleName());
        System.out.println(((Object)employeeId).getClass().getSimpleName());
        System.out.println(((Object)jobTitle).getClass().getSimpleName());
        System.out.println(((Object)bond).getClass().getSimpleName());
    }

}
```

```java
Output:
Double
Integer
String
String
```

Answer (score 0):

An `Object` instance can be type-tested in several ways and for array properties by checking its `Class` type like this:

```
public static <T> void typetest(final T t) {
 if (t != null) {
  
  final Class<? extends Object> clazz = t.getClass();
  // Check is an Object is an array 
  if (clazz.isArray()) {
    // Shows array Object type
    System.out.println("Is array of type: [" + clazz.getSimpleName() + "]");
  }
  
  // Check is an Object is an array / get a non-null result array class for array Object types 
  final Class<?> ct = clazz.getComponentType();
  if (ct != null) {
    // Shows array primitive/Object type
    if (ct.isPrimitive()) {
      System.out.println("Primitive array of type: [" + ct.getSimpleName() + "]");
    } else {
      System.out.println("Array of Object type: [" + ct.getSimpleName() + "]");
    }
  }
  
  // Since Java 12 there's also 
  final Class<?> arrayType = ct.arrayType();
  
  // Matches a Objects are instances of List 
  if (t instanceof List) {
    // ...
  // Matches a Objects are instances of Collection (i. e. List, Set...) 
  } else if (t instanceof Collection) {
    // ...
  // Matches a Objects are instances of Map (i. e. List, Set...) 
  } else if (t instanceof Map) {
  }
  
  // Matches all Objects that have List as superclass or implement interface 
  if (List.class.getClass().isAssignableFrom(clazz)) {
    // ...
  // Matches all Objects that have Collection as superclass or implement interface 
  } else if (Collection.class.getClass().isAssignableFrom(clazz)) {
    // ...
  // Matches all Objects that have Map as superclass or implement interface 
  } else if (Map.class.getClass().isAssignableFrom(clazz)) {
    // ...
  }
 }
}
```

Note, that it's possible to check against specific types and implemented interfaces or inheritance from superclasses with `isAssignableFrom()`.

If an Object was wrapped or cast beforehand, it's not possible to get back that type information, though, to my knowledge.

Another option is using `Array.getLength(arrayObject)`, which should work on all types of arrays, throwing an `IllegalArgumentException`, if the argument is not an array, which can be handled accordingly. This has the advantage of getting the array's size at once.