# Determining a 'type' in Java

Tags: java, types

Im new to Java, is there a method in Java that tells you the type of an Object?

For example in Python if you type

`type(34)` it would return `int`

`type('abc')` would return `string`

I've been looking everywhere but I can't find a way of doing it. Any help?

Thanks a lot.

Comment: Class cls = obj.getClass(); or you can do the other way around, for instance: if (obj instanceof String) { ... }

Comment: try http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3993982/how-to-check-type-of-variable-in-java

Answer (score 12):

The [`instanceof`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/specs/jls/se7/html/jls-15.html#jls-15.20.2) operator is the handiest way to do runtime type checking:

```
if (someObject instanceof String) {
    // It's a string
}
```

Alternately, on any instance, you can use [`getClass`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/Object.html#getClass%28%29), which gives you the `Class` instance for the type of the object.

```
Class c = someObject.getClass();
```

The `Class` instance will have a [`getName`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/Class.html#getName%28%29) method you can call to get a string version of the name (and lots of other handy methods).

You can get a `Class` object from a type name using `.class`, e.g.:

```
Class stringClass = String.class;
```

As Peter Lawrey points out in the comments, all of these assume you're dealing with an object reference, not a primitive. There's no way to do a runtime type check on a primitive, but that's okay, because unlike with object references (where your compile-time declaration may be `Object`), you always know what your primitive types are because of the declaration. It's only object types where this really comes up.

---

If you find yourself doing a lot of explicit type checks in your Java code, that can indicate structure/design issues. For the most part, you shouldn't need to check type at runtime. (There are, of course, exceptions.)

Comment: @PeterLawrey: Good point, I've added a bit on that (wouldn't mind your expert eye cast over the addition, actually, if you have a sec).

Answer (score 0):

Basically we can achieve our  goal by using the method overriding

```
   class GetType {
        void printType(byte x) {
            System.out.println(x + " is an byte");
        }
        void printType(int x) {
            System.out.println(x + " is an int");
        }
        void printType(float x) {
            System.out.println(x + " is an float");
        }
        void printType(double x) {
            System.out.println(x + " is an double");
        }
        void printType(char x) {
            System.out.println(x + " is an char");
        }
    } 
    public static void main(String args[]) {
          double doubleVar = 1.5;
          int intVar = 7;
          float floatVar = 1f;

          GetType objType = new GetType();
          objType.printType(doubleVar);
          objType.printType(intVar);
          objType.printType(floatVar);
    }
```