# While Not Condition

Tags: java, loops, while-loop, int

How can I say the following:

```
while(input is not an int){
do this
}
```

I tried this code but I know it's wrong:

```
 int identificationnumber;
 Scanner sc3 = new Scanner(System.in);
identificationnumber = sc3.nextInt();

while( identificationnumber != int){ // this line is wrong 

Scanner sc4 = new Scanner(System.in);
identificationnumber = sc4.nextInt();

}
```

Any suggestions please.Thanks.

Comment: So you get an int and want to check if it is not one? What else should it be then?

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2674554/how-know-a-variable-type-in-java

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Javadocs are your friend: http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/util/Scanner.html

`nextInt()` throws an exception if the next token isn't an `int`. You're probably looking for `hasNextInt()`

Also, why are you creating a new `Scanner` every time you loop? (Or at all - you already have one before the loop)

Answer (score 6):

try :

```
while (! scanner.hasNextInt()) { // while the next token is not an int...
    scanner.next();              // just skip it
}
int i = scanner.nextInt();       // then read the int
```

Answer (score 1):

Scanner throws an exception before getting to that line
http://docs.oracle.com/javase/1.5.0/docs/api/java/util/Scanner.html#nextInt()

The following code will work:

```
    int i = 0;
    while(true){
        Scanner scan = new Scanner(System.in);
        try{
            i = scan.nextInt();
        }catch (Exception e) {
            break;
        }
    }
```

Answer (score 1):

You want this?

```
String identificationnumber;
Scanner scanner = new Scanner(System.in);//Only one Scanner is needed

while (scanner.hasNext()) { // Is there has next input?
    identificationnumber = scanner.next();//Get next input
    try {
        Integer.parseInt(identificationnumber);//Try to parse to integer
        System.out.println(identificationnumber + " is a number!");
    } catch (NumberFormatException e) {
        System.out.println(identificationnumber + " is not a number!");
    }
}
```

Comment: Thanks for this - but it just leaves me in an infinite loop. Is there a way I can do this with a for loop?

Comment: @ayokunleadeosun If you want break the loop you can define a end flag string or just use "control + c"

Answer (score 0):

By writing sc3.nextInt() I assume you always get an int back, so checking for a non int seems a bit strange.

Maybe its better to return a string with the number inside. If the string is empty stop (you can just check against "") and otherwise convert it to an integer.

Comment: I used sc3.nextInt to get the input into an int variable.

Comment: a hasNextInt method is indeed the better solution.

Answer (score 0):

Use [nextInt()](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/1.5.0/docs/api/java/util/Scanner.html#nextInt%28%29) method of scanner class.

It throws,

> InputMismatchException - if the next token does not match the
>   Integer regular expression, or is out of range

Answer (score 0):

You should be doing this:

```
if (sc3.hasNextInt())
```

Check this out: [How to use Scanner to accept only valid int as input](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2912817/how-to-use-scanner-to-accept-only-valid-int-as-input)

With regards to class/type comparison, read this: [What is the difference between instanceof and Class.isAssignableFrom(...)?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/496928/what-is-the-difference-between-instanceof-and-class-isassignablefrom)