# Identifying the type of data

Tags: java, floating-point

How to identify decimal portion value that exists with a float data type?
If the decimal part results as zero, exempting the decimal portion shall be a   good practice. How this can be achieved when dealing with float values making   it easeful?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How know a variable type in java?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2674554/how-know-a-variable-type-in-java)

Comment: What does that code have to do with the problem you are facing? Please post the code that shows that you have made an attempt at resolving you our problem.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your variables `num1` and `num2` are both floats not integers as mentioned in your question, I guess that what you want to achieve is to find a way to know if a given float has decimals or not and for this you can proceed as next:

```
float f = 46.0f;
if (f % 1.0 == 0.0){
    System.out.printf("float without decimal %.0f%n", f);
} else {
    System.out.printf("float with decimals %.2f%n", f);
}
```

**Output:**

```
float without decimal 46
```

Comment: Based on the input provided by the user, I want the values to be stored W.R.T the data types of the input. Can it be done ?

Comment: I don't understand, please reformulate

Comment: Suppose that 12 and 34 are inputted numbers which are of integer, it adds up to 46. The resulted value be 46.0 as it is of float data type. I want the output to be of integer data type and eradicate the decimal part.

Comment: try it, you will see that is works, as show in my response update

Answer (score 0):

```
inputValue.getClass().getName()
```

example: `value: type = java.lang.String`

```
inputValue.getClass().getSimpleName();
```

example: `value: String`

Answer (score 0):

Ended up with the below solution.

```
if (Value - (int) Value) != 0)
   //Contains the decimal portion
else
   //Decimal portion doesn't exist
```

Helps in identifying the type of value stored and avoid unnecessary usage of decimal portion if an int value.