# Java get variable type not working

Tags: java

According to this [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2674554/how-do-you-know-a-variable-type-in-java), `getClass().getName()` should give me the solution. I'm not sure why this is not working.

Error:

```
/tmp/java_i8lW4s/HelloWorld.java:35: error: cannot find symbol
    System.out.print(z.class.getName());
                     ^
  symbol:   class z
  location: class HelloWorld
1 error
```

Code:

```
public class HelloWorld
{
  public static void main(String[] args)
  {
    int x, y;
    double z;

    x = 10;
    y = 5;

    z = 10 / 5;

    System.out.print(z.getClass().getName());
  }
}
```

Comment: `z` is not an object. It is a *primitive data type*. You **cannot** call methods on *primitive data types*

Comment: You can't call `getClass()` (or any other method) on a primitive variable such as a `double`.  Also, your code doesn't quite match the error that you've shown, so you're probably compiling a different version from what you've shown here.

Comment: Why would you want to do that? You know exactly what it is, i.e. a `double`. It cannot be anything else.

Comment: The other answers address the issue, but like @Andreas asked, what is the use case of this? there are other, better ways of checking types of primitives that don't involve changing all of them to instances of classes. Also, you should start using an IDE like eclipse to do your development. It would have highlighted this error and told you what the issue was so you could figure it out without re-compiling. It would have also given you a more descriptive error.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`z` is not an object it is a primitive type. Try to change it in `Double`.

For example: `short`, `int`, `long`, `float` and `double` are only numeric data primitive type.

Those are the equivalent of `Short`, `Integer`, `Long`, `Float` and `Double`.

So you should ask yourself, why have primitive type and object representation of same things. And what's the difference.

Basically they should be the same thing, for example you can add an `Integer` to an `int` transparently.

```
  Integer t = 2 ;
  int i = t + 1; // i now is 3
```

I also would suggest to have a look at [Autoboxing and Autounboxing in java](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/data/autoboxing.html)

Comment: Is there a standard way to check for primitive type?  I tried `((Object)z).getClass().getName();` but when I did `double z; z = (int) 10/3;`, it still gave me `java.lang.Double`

Comment: The question is: "may I ask to a primitive type which kind of type is?", if this is your question, you don't need to do this, you know it at compile time.

Answer (score 1):

If you define it as

```
int a = 0;
```

then it is a **primitive**

What you want is to be able to call on a `Integer` class is done by defining it in the **Integer wrapper class** (*same goes for all other primitives that has a wrapper*)

```
Integer a = 0;
```

See for instance `javadoc` for [Integer](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/Integer.html), [Double](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/Double.html)

Comment: @Daniel Reed, to the question below, a primitive does not store anything in memory but the value, thus you cannot acces what type it is. (need 50 rep.... to comment...)